# How to make activity to preview a wallpaper before actually setting it

Tags: android, kotlin

I am making a wallpaper application, and I want to allow the user to set an image as the wallpaper. However, I wanted to give the user a "preview" of how the wallpaper would look before setting it. This preview is something very similar to how at least Samsung phones allow the user to see the wallpaper on their home screen, and move the wallpaper if it's wide so they can arrange it according to how they wish. Please see screenshot of how this looks.

[image] [image]

The problem I'm having is I have no idea how to get the active widgets and icons to show this preview appropriately. Is there something I'm missing in the official Android docs to do this?

I've tried to find ways to get a screenshot with a transparent background of the home screen, and then underlay this on that to show something similar to the preview, but unable to find how to exactly do this.